# python packaging results in import error

Tags: python-3.x, namespaces, python-module

I have a boost python generating a shared object to be used with python in /home/user/service/org/boost_py.so  (This folder does not contain a __init__.py)

and /home/user/service is part of sys.path so when I need to use this ,just do

```
import org.boost_py   #works
```

Now I have added a pure python module in a different directory.

```
/home/user/service/pure_python/org/
                                  __init__.py
                                  tester.py
```

__init__.py contains

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

Now when sys.path is

```
['/home/user/service/','/home/user/service/pure_python']
```

and I

```
import org.boost_py   #ImportError: No module named 'org.boost_py'
```

but I can import org.tester. How to import both org.tester and org.boost_py ? (I cannot change the location of either)

**update**:
Found pth file with following contents in pure_python directory

```
import sys, types, os;
p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('org',));
ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py'));
m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('org', types.ModuleType('org'));
mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]);
(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no file or directory `boost_py` in 'pure_python/org ', this produces the error.

If it exists please edit the question!

Alternatively, the path of the boost could be not in the path browser, then it just wont recognize the file.